# css - float right disables links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-float, broken-links

Why are my links becoming disabled when I try to make the span they are in float right?

HTML:

```
<span id="spnLoginRegister">
    <a href="login.htmls" type="text/html">Login</a>
    | 
    <a href="register.html" type="text/html">Register</a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#spnLoginRegister{
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

-- or --

```
#spnLoginRegister{
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Both of these CSS methods disable to links. Then I remove the `float: right;` part, the links work just fine. I feel like the solution is very simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Here is the link the the site: http://friendshipodyssey.com/

Comment: Somehow it works on me - http://jsfiddle.net/nX6r8/

Comment: No problem with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i saw your online page , You have to delete this property :

`position: relative;`

from this id :

`#hgpHeaders`

And your problem with be fixed .

Comment: That fixed it. Why did that effect it?

Comment: Because of the position was not correct and no needed + you could also give width for that element and that would be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here in your code :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7pvh/) + [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CraX7/)

Please check your other CSS codes and its better to user the `<span>` tag like this:

```
<a href="login.htmls" type="text/html"><span>Login</span></a>
```

Try using `<div>` instead of `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site, http://friendshipodyssey.com/

Solution:

Just put span id="spnLoginRegister" & hgroup id="hgpHeaders" inside a DIV and give CSS property as width: 100% & height:150px,

Also for #hgpHeaders, apply CSS property float:left.

Hopefully it solves your issues